# carousel for bootstrap4 slides did not next and prev When I click it

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, bootstrap-4

hi Every one would you help me please regarding my project I'm getting frustrating of  the error it would not next when I try to click next in 
*edge browser* the carousel  would not work its button

you can view this information about the carousel that I  have choosen here's the link http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#carouselprev

```
<section id ="Carousel">
       <div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide"data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
     <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="carousel-item active">
         <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="girl_holdCamera.jpg" alt="woman holding a cannon camera">
            <div class = "carousel-caption">
              <h3>A woman holding camera</h3>
                <p>she is probably holding a cannon camera to take picture</p>
            </div>
       </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="heart.jpg" alt="heart forming by thiere hand">
               <div class = "carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Building a heart with Two hands</h3>
                     <p>they build a heart with the use of thiere hands to keep them promesis</p>
                </div>
         </div>
         <div class="carousel-item">
           <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="Smart-guy-holding-beautiful-girl-in-arms.jpg" alt="guy holding girl in his hand">
              <div class = "carousel-caption">
                <h3>Guy and Pretty woman hugging for the First time</h3>
                  <p> They were happy to meet each of them</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-home" role="button" data-slide="prev">
             <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-home" role="button" data-slide= "next">
             <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
         </a>
   </div>
   </section>


    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you post a link to a live version of the issue?

Comment: yes! @Patrick here the link http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#carouselprev  scroll up then you can see the indacators that carousel that I have choosen, but when I try to paste it would not next and prev to my microsoft edge